# Can I move a branch and history from one repository to another in GitHub?

Tags: github

Being a consulting company, we work on dozens of projects, some small and some large. We use the 10-repo business account in GitHub and it is getting crowded.

Most of our projects are not active. We deliver it to the client but maybe we will hear back from them in 6 months or a year asking for a bug to be fixed or another feature to be included.

I would like to move these projects into a single repository, while retaining their history. I would like to establish a Repository such as "Completed Projects" where the code and history just goes to die unless I need to make changes in the future.

If I need to work on them, I can do so in this repository, or if there is going to be a lot of work, I can pull it out into one of my unused repositories and work on it there.

I'm trying to avoid paying large monthly fees for repositories of inactive code.

How can I do this with GitHub?

I do realize I can host Git myself on my server as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to fetch the branches of interest from the existing repositories into your "completed projects" repo, and git will work out that there are no common commits and deal with it appropriately.  Push that up to github, and you're done.

Comment: This option will retain the history?

Comment: Of course, just like any other fetch into another repository.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just clone the repository and archive it, saving github for active projects?